# How to perform a port-forward on microk8s and send that process to the background?

Tags: command-line, bash, services, kubernetes, microk8s

I am trying to run this command:

```bsh
microk8s kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 10443:443
```

But the output is the following:

```bsh
└─[$] <> microk8s kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 10443:443
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:10443 -> 8443
Forwarding from [::1]:10443 -> 8443
```

And this is a "always on" process, is there anyway to perform this configuration without me having to keep a terminal open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with microk8s specifically, but if it behaves like a standard k8s system, then you could create another Service using type NodePort. That would expose the dashboard on a local port on the kubernetes node.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-dash
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    app: k8s-dash
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: https
    nodePort: 30443
    port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
```

Change the selector to match what ever the labels the dashboard uses.

Alternatively you could deploy an Ingress Controller (like this one: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress ) and use an Ingress resource to expose it.

The ingress controller is the more secure route, because you can apply additional protections like ACL, OAUTH2, etc.

Editor nodes:
On microk8s the following service manifest works fine (note the changes to targetPort, and the selector):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-dash
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: https
    nodePort: 30443
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
    protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score -1):

Though I am not much familiar with Kubernetes, but a general way to keep a command running in background is by using `nohup` at the beginning and `&` at the end.

e.g.

`nohup microk8s kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 10443:443 &`